# How to make Custom NavigationDrawer or resize them in android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I want to make a Navigation Drawer in android like this. Is there anyway to resize the default navbar in android. If possible then how to do it?
[Navigation Drawer Should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYEqm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think i get my solution. To change navigation drawer width i have to change the width of **android.support.design.widget.NavigationView** . Now my code is something like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="100sp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.Android)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/conteiner_frame"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            <!-- Layout of Drawer -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> Java code

```
 private List<SlideMenuItem> list = new ArrayList<>(); \\ the list of menu items

SlideMenuItem menuItem0 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.CLOSE, R.drawable.icn_close);
    list.add(menuItem0);
    SlideMenuItem menuItem = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.BUILDING, R.drawable.icn_1);  \\first parameter is the id of menu item,the second is the icon resouce
    list.add(menuItem);
    SlideMenuItem menuItem2 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.BOOK, R.drawable.icn_2);
    list.add(menuItem2);

    viewAnimator = new ViewAnimator<>(this, list, contentFragment, drawerLayout,
```

Comment: Thanks for you're reply but I solved it. But can you help me to make the animation for navigation drawer items?